# Calculate $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X]$ for each $s < t$

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, filtrations

I need help understanding a solution, I have two thirds figured out but I cannot understand one part, I explain:

**Problem:**

Let $X$, $Y$ be two random variables in a probability space ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}$). Define the process $X$ by:

$$X_t = \begin{cases} Z \mbox{ if }t\lt t_0,  \quad \\ Y \mbox{ if }t\ge t_0 \end{cases}  $$

Where $t_0\gt0$ is a fixed time

*Apologies for the format! I copied other people's code for this on stack exchange and it does not seem to work!*

**Question:**

Assume $Z$ and $Y$ are integrable. Calculate $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X]$ for each $s < t$.

**Solution:**

For $s<t<t_0$, it is clear we have $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X] = E[X_s|\mathcal{F}_s^X]  = X_s$

We can also view this as $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X] = E[X_s|\mathcal{F}_s^X] = E[Z|\sigma(Z)] = Z$

For $t_0 \le s < t$, it is clear we have $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X] = E[X_s|\mathcal{F}_s^X]  = X_s$

We can also view this as $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X] = E[X_s|\mathcal{F}_s^X] = E[Y|\sigma(Z,Y)] = Y$

**My Problem:**

What I do not know how to describe is for $s<t_0 \le t$, what is $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X]$?

The solution says, for $s<t_0 \le t$, $E[X_t|\mathcal{F}_s^X] = E[Y|Z]$

And I am confused, how does this follow? Also, is $E[Z|\sigma(Z)] = E[Z|Z]$ an abuse of notation, or are they different things?

ANY help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly $E[X|Y]$ is probably defined to be $E[X|\sigma(Y)]$ Since you are after all taking conditional expectation w.r.t. a sub $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma(Y)$ is the only one which makes natural sense. (You can of course consult [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_a_random_variable) or your textbook in these cases).

For your problem: Clearly $t\geq t_{0}$ implies that $X_{t} = Y$. For $s< t_{0}\leq t$ you know that $X_{s} = Z$. Recall now that the definition of $\mathcal{F}^{X}_{s}$ is the sigma algebra generated by the union of $X_{r}$ for $0\leq r \leq s$. But these are all $Z$, so it is precisely the sigma algebra generated by $Z$, $\sigma(Z)$. Therefore
$$E[X_{t}|\mathcal{F}_{s}^{X}]=E[Y|\sigma(Z)]=E[Y|Z].$$

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for the excellent clarification!